# How can I convert this string to a javascript Date object?

Tags: javascript

I have a string with a specific format which I am trying to convert to a Date object. I was hoping `var dateObject = new Date(myString)` would be sufficient but it won't work. So I tried breaking up the string into smaller pieces, and that didn't work either.

```
var str = '2015-02-20 11:00'; 
var obj = new Date(str.substr(2, 4), str.substr(5, 7), str.substr(8, 10), str.substr(13, 15), str.substr(16, 18));
// Above code yields invalid date
```

[JS-Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j5kaC/)

How can I make a date object out of my string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try just

```
var str = '2015-02-20 11:00';
var obj = new Date(str);
```

works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/j5kaC/1/

If for some strange reason that doesn't work, split it up and pass it to the Date constructor in the appropriate places

```
var str = '2015-02-20 11:00';

var arr  = str.split(' ');
var time = arr.pop().split(':')
var arr2 = arr.shift().split('-');

var date = new Date(arr2[0], arr2[1]-1, arr2[2], time.shift(), time.pop(), 0, 0);

console.log(date);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j5kaC/2/)

Comment: @Weblurk - in what browser ?

Comment: @adaneo Firefox. But your second example almost works. It gets the month wrong by 1. So if I write 2012-02-20 it converts it to 2012 Mars 20th.

Comment: Testing now, the month is wrong because javascript months are zero based, just subtract 1

Comment: Aha did not know that about JS months. Thanks!

Comment: You can shorten this a little using the fact `'2015-02-20 11:00'.split(/[ :-]/); // ["2015", "02", "20", "11", "00"]`, additionally the code would then contain a smiley face which makes it just awesome by default.

Comment: @PaulS. - That's cool, how about a one-liner with that thing -> http://jsfiddle.net/j5kaC/5/

Comment: @adeneo you're forgetting our special little month friend again D:

Comment: @PaulS. - Yes I did, fuc/)#"¤ javascript zero based month crap.

Answer (score 0):

Change your line of code to this

```
var str = '2015-02-20 11:00'; 
var obj = new Date(str.substr(0, 4), str.substr(5, 2), str.substr(8, 2), str.substr(11, 2), str.substr(14, 2));
```

It will work.

You use the ISO format:  YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

For example:
new Date('2011-04-11')

or

new Date('2011-04-11T11:51:00')

Comment: I read somewhere that doesn't work with IE<9, hence my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Because you already have the units in the same order as the *Date* constructor takes them, you could do it this way..

```
var str = '2015-02-20 11:00',
    args = str.split(/[ :-]/).map(Number);
args[1] = args[1] - 1; // fix months;

var d = new Date; // this and the next line are separated otherwise
Date.apply(d, args); // you end up with a String and not a Date
d; // Wed Mar 05 2014 14:13:47 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

Trying in the console of *IE11* emulating *IE9* works fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your format is quite close to the standard one, just replace the whitespace with `T` :

```
var date = new Date(str.split(' ').join('T'));
```

http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15

Just checked IE8. Doesn't work indeed...